# Could a crypto system that uses non-FIPS crypto but then upgrades complete to FIPS be FIPS certified?

Tags: fips-140

I know most people around here (including myself) are anti-FIPS, but I have a FIPS related question.

Could a crypto system that is not FIPS, e.g. one based on primitives like Curve25519, achieve FIPS compliance if it is capable of upgrading to FIPS algorithms/implementations in a way that is complete. By complete I mean in the upgraded mode it is using only FIPS compliant crypto and the upgrade occurs in such a way that all the previous security guarantees are re-confirmed using FIPS crypto.

Or would the mere presence of non-FIPS crypto at any stage of the system invalidate it for FIPS certification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a device that is FIPS certified need not be restricted to using only FIPS-approved algorithms.  For example, in your case, FIPS has no problems with you supporting Curve25519, *as long as the user can turn it off*.  That is, the device will need to be able to be set in a mode that it performs only FIPS approved algorithms (and the FIPS approval documentation will have to explain precisely how to do that).

You specifically asked about 'crypto system'; if you're asking about a protocol, a protocol is not FIPS approved; FIPS approved devices, not protocols.

Comment: That's close but not exactly my question. What if the protocol uses Curve25519 at first but then upgrades completely and cleanly?

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. A FIPS compliant "device" (which as far as I know can include a binary program) must use only FIPS-approved crypto but can speak any protocol as long as it can do so in a FIPS-approved manner.